# Is there a way to automatically find errors made by the Watershed tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, watershed

I've delineated the watershed of near 7000 reservoirs with the *Watershed* tool in ArcGIS 10.1 and converted them in polygons. As you can see in the image bellow, some mistakes were made because the pour point didn't snap properly.

**Is there a way to automatically find these errors in my Shapefile so I can redo them?**

[image]

Comment: what exactly is the error here? I assume that the blue polygon is the reservoir and the red is the created watershed? I've done a little work with generating watersheds for wetlands and never required a vector stream network as a watershed is related to slope/flow direction.

Comment: Yes that's the error. It created the Watershed beside the one I want.

Comment: Does the watershed make sense when considered in combination with the DEM for the area? It's not impossible for the reservoir to be completely outside the watershed.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't make sense, no.

Answer (score 2):

In my old job I had developed a tool that would identify this scenario so you could go back and replace the pour point. It required the vector network (do you have that ?) and tracing upstream to the source, the source being defined as the furthest point upstream. It was then a simple test of "is source point inside catchment polygon". If not, then you had the situation as shown in your image.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to the vector river network. Just a DEM.

Comment: Review [this](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//009z0000005z000000.htm) page to see a sequence on extracting the raster river network. Then use this [tool](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/How_Stream_to_Feature_works/009z00000067000000/) to convert to vector dataset, at that point you could build a geometric network.